# In "Partials" by Dan Wells, which one of the scouts is a Partial?

Tags: books, partials

I'm not sure if any of you have read the *Partials* series by Dan Wells (It's an excellent book series that deserves more attention then it has gotten) but if you have maybe you can help me. In the first book it is implied by several characters that one or both of the scouts is a Partial. I have just finished reading through the series and I feel that most of the questions I had at the end were answered except this one. Which one (if any) of the scouts was a Partial? Does this question not have any answer in the books, or did I miss something in my first read though?

Comment: Stay around. I'm reading the series to answer your question.

Comment: Two down, one to go. I think I already know though.

Comment: @Jonah you read fast.

Comment: Ok, all done. Ready to answer.

Comment: @Jonah ok I will be waiting for your answer.  By the way out of curiosity did what did you think of the books?

Comment: It was very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Probably neither

This is the explanation presented by Mkele:

> “We need to find out why,” Kira insisted. “One of our scouts may have
>   been a Partial—”
>
> “Or he may simply have been interrogated in the field,” said Mkele. “A
>   tortured soldier is a simpler explanation, and therefore a more likely
>   one, than a widespread infiltration of our entire society.”
>
> —*Partials*

He's probably right. Consider:

1. Scruffy killed a Partial soldier. Contrary to what trigger-happy Haru though, this would have been a very improbable action for an infiltrator to take. In addition, a spy would probably have known that they wouldn't be trusted when they returned, even if they wouldn't have counted on being shot on sight, and would simply not have come back.

   > Scruffy looked behind, shrugged, and handed Haru his weapon. Before he
   >   could even pick up the prisoner, Haru shot him in the head. Kira
   >   yelped, Scruffy toppled to the ground, and Haru shot him again.
   >
   > “What the hell are you doing?” Jayden shouted. “I told you,” said
   >   Haru, “as far as I’m concerned, they’re both guilty. I’m not taking
   >   any more Partials home than I have to.”
   >
   > “He saved us!” Jayden shouted. “He killed a Partial soldier!”
   >
   > —*Partials*

   Of course, this only rules out Scruffy, not Skinny.
2. The Partials didn't really seem to have much interest in infiltration. They didn't seem to have much interest in humanity at all, in fact, until they realized the humans might hold the key to their own survival. **The presence of Partial agents among the humans is never mentioned by any Partial or Trustee.**
3. The radio was so distorted that Kira couldn't tell who was talking.

   > A radio crackled quietly. “Timmy calling Jimmy.” The voice was
   >   distorted enough by static that Kira couldn’t tell if it was Skinny or
   >   Scruffy.
   >
   > —*Partials*

   This means it could have been anyone, including one of the Partials looking for them.
4. Why betray them then?

   > Kira leaned back against the wall, her legs weak, feeling the sudden
   >   need for support. The ramifications were terrifying, but the logic …
   >   didn’t hold up. “Why now?” she asked. “If they wanted us dead, they
   >   could have done it at any time—what do they gain by betraying us here,
   >   in the middle of nowhere?”
   >
   > —*Partials*

   Of course, we later learn a possible reason: to get a human test subject.
5. It would have been very difficult for a Partial to remain hidden in a human settlement. Their emotional expression is extremely different from most humans,  medical examination would probably reveal their nature, and most can't bear to be apart from the Link for long. An espionage model could probably manage it, though.
6. Perhaps most important: **If one or more Partial agents were already embedded in the population, why bother with sending squadron to collect a human test subject?** They could easily just kidnap someone, especially a fellow soldier, without nearly so much trouble.

### But on the other hand...

1. We also know that Steve, [a.k.a Skinny, probably lived](http://www.thefandom.net/exclusive-interview-dan-wells-author-partials/), at least through that sequence:

   > There are two minor characters in the Manhattan sequence of the book
   >   named Nick and Steve–or Skinny and Scruffy, as Kira calls them. Nick
   >   and Steve are friends of mine, and I put them into every book I write:
   >   Steve always lives and Nick always dies. I don’t know why, it just
   >   amuses me.

   This could indicate that he was a Partial. Of course, he could also have been taken back for Morgan's experiments.
2. Jayden believed that they couldn't have gotten the passcode from Steve that quickly.

   > “They couldn’t have tortured anyone that fast,” said Jayden, standing
   >   slowly. “There’s no way they could have gotten the code words unless…”
   >   He paused. “What about… It couldn’t be, that’s insane.”
   >
   > —*Partials*

   On the other hand, there's no reason to think this might not be the case. Most of these soldiers haven't seen proper combat, for while if ever. Many people would give up information under field torture, or even without any prompting, just to spare themselves.

So I would say it is **most likely** that one of the scouts simply gave up the information and was taken prisoner, but it is still possible one was nonetheless a Partial.